# Shopify liquid pattern matching using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, shopify

I would like to add a new line to shopify liquid file (basically it's an HTML file with some variables) after I find a pattern I look for in the liquid string.

As this is a valid HTML file by saying after I mean add a new line as a new element in the html in a way that doesn't break the layout of the html.

I was thinking of using BeautifulSoap to load the string and do the manipulations, what do you think?

Is there a better way?

How would you do the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup won't maintain the alignment of the code. You can align the code as spaces or tabs in Beautiful Soup but then it will not be the same as it was before. Beautiful Soup will also remove the white spaces. I suggest you do a string comparison and replace where ever you want to. Below is an example wherein an HTML code was inserted before the `</body>` tag ends.

```
#get the asset
parsed_html = shopify.Asset.find('layout/theme.liquid').value

#get the position where you want to insert the HTML
index = parsed_html.find('</body>')

#insert the HTML
parsed_html = parsed_html[:index] + "\n\nYour HTML code\n\n" + parsed_html[index:]
```